# How do I update Git on Mac OS Lion, if the original version has been installed by XCode 4.1

Tags: xcode, macos, git, rvm, macports

I would like to update git on my XCode 4.1 development system. It got initially installed by installing XCode 4.1. Do I use RVM or MacPorts? I also would like to add some features like SVN integration to the current installation.

Comment: Use http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Answer (score 0):

MacPorts is a whole package managing system, just like Debians dpkg packages.

To install it using Macports you only have to run the Macports installer and then install git via

```
sudo port install git-core +svn
```

This will install git with the mentioned svn integration (Bi-directional subversion repository support).

If you do not want to use Macports there are the following alternatives:

- Homebrew
- Fink